# reading and executing sql queries into pandas data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a long-assed sql query that runs quite well in Python, into a data frame
but I have hundreds of them, so I tried creating a function that reads my files and executes them.
The sql statements look like this:

```
"SELECT IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Proc',1, \
 ....\
 120 lines
 ....\
dbo.MY_data_value"
```

This is the function

```
def Execute_SQL_from_a_File(filename,home,conn1):
    FORMAT1 = '%Y%m%d%H%M'
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    KIC53 = pd.read_sql(sqlFile, conn1)
    f_out = home + out1 + ".xls"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f_out)
    KIC53.to_excel(writer,f_out)
    writer.save()
```

This is what calls the function:

```
Execute_SQL_from_a_File(QRYHOME + "qryBook" + str(BNUM) + "_" + str(IND) + ".sql", BNUM, home, conn1)
```

when I run the query as function I received this error:

```
: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The 
identifier that starts with 'SELECT 
IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Proc',1, 
\\\nIIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Subm',2, 
\\\nIIf(Left([Milestone_N' is too long. Maximum length is 128.")
```

I cant figure out why I'm getting the length error, because I can run the same query by creating sqlFile as one long string:

```
"SELECT IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Proc',1, \
 ....\
 120 lines
 ....\
dbo.MY_data_value"
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have a column name that has more than 128 char in it? starting with Milestone_N

Comment: Can you post that problematic query part? You omit most of your SQL. Since you are looping, maybe one of the *hundreds* of file has a syntax error. Try printing *filename* in the function so you know which one needs troubleshooting. Then open it and check. I doubt it can run on its own.

Comment: 1. None of the column names is > 32 
2. All the queries break at the same place, so I'm fairly certain it in the way the query is being read.
3. All the queries run fine when hardcoded into python
4. Here are the first six lines of the 128 line query:

     "SELECT IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Proc',1, \
     IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Subm',2, \
     IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Cond',3, \
     IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Resu',4, \
     IIf(Left([Milestone_Next_Expected],4)='Fund',9,0)))))))) AS [DELETE- 
     sortby], \

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is:
1. the sql script script does not require any line continuation symbols, "\"
    and does not need to be encased in quotes
2. The correct way to read the input file is:

```
file=open(filename,'r')
SQLfile = s = " ".join(file.readlines())
```

Now, when the code is executed, via pd.read_sql_query(SQLfile, conn1)
there are no errors